# Selenium - How to add integer variable in xpath using python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

Im new with selenium/python and that my problem:
I have a simple site with a couple of news.
I try to write script that iterates over all news, open each one, do something and goes back to all other news
All news have same xpath, difference only with last symbol - i try to put this symbol as variable and loop over all news, with increment my variable after every visited news:

```
     x = len(driver.find_elements_by_class_name('cards-news-event'))
            print (x)
            for i in range(x):
     driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/**a["'+i+'"]**').click()
     do something                
      i = i+1
```

Python return error: "Except type "str", got "int" instead. Google it couple of hours but really can't deal with it 
Very appreciate for any help

Comment: Did you try `a["'+str(i)+'"]` or `'.../a["%s"]' % i`? P.S. Do not use absolute XPath expressions

Comment: There's also `'.../a["{}"]'.format(i)` with python3 and `f'.../a["{i}"]'` starting with python3.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to add a string and a int which is is why the exception. Use str(i) instead of i

```
xpath_string = '/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/**a[{0}]**'.format(str(i))    
driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath_string).click()
```

In the above the {0} is replaced with str(i). You can use .format to substitute multiple variables in a string by providing them as positional values, it is more elegant and easy to use that using + to concatenate strings.

refer: http://thepythonguru.com/python-string-formatting/